# Solve is not able to solve trivial system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

Mathematica can solve the following equation:

```
In[1]  = Solve[{a == b + c}, c]
Out[1] = {{c -> a - b}}
```

But it does not solve the equation, if I add additional information on b:

```
In[2]  = Solve[{a == b + c, b == 1}, c]
Out[2] = {}
```

If I substitute by hand, it works:

```
In[3]  = Solve[{a == 1 + c}, c]
Out[3] = {{c -> -1 + a}}
```

The "system" defined above was clearly not under- or overdetermined. Even Refining the variables to real numbers does not help.

```
In[4] = RefiQne[Solve[{a == b + c, b == 1}, c], {Element[{a, b, c}, Reals] && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0}]
```

How can I help Mathematica to use additional information?

Comment: This has been explained in the **Possible Issues** of document of `Solve`: "`Solve` results do not depend on whether some of the input equations contain only parameters…  Use `MaxExtraConditions` to specify the number of parameter conditions allowed. "

Comment: `Solve[{a == b + c, b == 1}, {c, b}]` also works.

Comment: Why the close vote? This looks like a legitimate question. The connection to the documentation snippet quoted by @xzczd is very non-obvious to me!

Comment: @becko Because I didn't quote corresponding example in the document. If you check the full section in the document, it's quite obvious: https://i.stack.imgur.com/em7s3.png

Comment: Also, `Solve[{a == b + c}, c] /. b -> 1` or `Simplify[Solve[{a == b + c}, c], b == 1]`